# Accessing IDs in React components for requesting data and rendering it

Tags: reactjs, state, router

I have a question regarding good practices when accessing an ID on a page's component in order to fetch the content to fill it. Here's an example:

Let's say I have a page PersonList in which I fetch for their names and IDs to populate a list. I also have a page called PersonDetails linked by a button for each person in the list. When I click the "show person's details" button I'll be redirected to PersonDetails and use the ID to fetch this single person data and populate the details page.

I could send the ID from PersonList to PersonDetails using the state and retrieve it using the useLocation hook. The problem is that if I access the URL without coming from the list first, it'll break.

I could also grab the ID from the URL, so it should never break. The problem is, someone told me that this is a bad practice in general that could reveal some problems but this someone never told me exactly why.

I would like to see some perspectives on that matter. Any suggestions, comments or good practices regarding that subject.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question is too broad and hypothetical. We aren't a discussion forum.

Comment: If PersonDetails is the child component of PersonList, you can pass the id as props.
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html
Otherwise you can pass it as query params.